# Different 'states' in my canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**The Problem**

I am having a problem where to start when changing my game to include different states, I understand why states are used and they make so much sense to me but I am finding it rather hard to implement.

**The Question**

Would it be possible for me to edit my exciting code (shown below) to include states so that when you press play for example, the play state appears and lets you play the game?

[image]

I believe this shows what I am asking.

**The Code**

```
<div style id="canvas">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:5px solid #410b11" height="320" width="480">
            <p>Your browser does not support HTML5!</p>
        </canvas>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Referencing the canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var width = canvas.getAttribute('width');
            var height = canvas.getAttribute('height');

            //Finding the position of the mouse
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;

            //Images
            var bgImage = new Image();
            var logoImage = new Image();
            var playImage = new Image();
            var instructImage = new Image();
            var settingsImage = new Image();
            var aboutImage = new Image();
            var peaceImage = new Image();

            var backgroundY = 0;
            var speed = 1;

            //Arrays below used for mouse over function
            var buttonX = [130,110,130,160];
            var buttonY = [100,140,180,220];
            var buttonWidth = [96,260,182,160];
            var buttonHeight = [40,40,40,40];

            var peaceX = [0,0];
            var peaceY = [0,0];
            var peaceWidth = 35;
            var peaceHeight = 35;

            var peaceVisible = false;
            var peaceSize = peaceWidth;
            var peaceRotate = 0;

            var frames = 30;
            var timerId = 0;
            var fadeId = 0;
            var time = 0.0;

            peaceImage.src = "Images/peace.png";
            bgImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, backgroundY);
            };
            bgImage.src = "Images/background.png";
            logoImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(logoImage, 50, -10);
            }
            logoImage.src = "Images/logo.png";
            playImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[0], buttonY[0]);
            }
            playImage.src = "Images/play.png";
            instructImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[1]);
            }
            instructImage.src = "Images/instructions.png";
            settingsImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(settingsImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2]);
            }
            settingsImage.src = "Images/settings.png";
            aboutImage.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(aboutImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3]);
            }
            aboutImage.src = "Images/about.png";

            timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);

            function update() {
                clear();
                move();
                draw();
            }
            function clear() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }
            function move(){
                backgroundY -= speed;
                if(backgroundY == -1 * height){
                    backgroundY = 0;
                }
                if(peaceSize == peaceWidth){
                    peaceRotate = -1;
                }
                if(peaceSize == 0){
                    peaceRotate = 1;
                }
                peaceSize += peaceRotate;
            }


            function draw(){

                context.drawImage(bgImage, 0, backgroundY);
                context.drawImage(logoImage, 50,-10);
                context.drawImage(playImage, buttonX[1], buttonY[0]);
                context.drawImage(instructImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[1]);
                context.drawImage(settingsImage, buttonX[2], buttonY[2]);
                context.drawImage(aboutImage, buttonX[3], buttonY[3]);
                    if(peaceVisible == true){
                    context.drawImage(peaceImage, peaceX[0] - (peaceSize/2), peaceY[0], peaceSize, peaceHeight);
                    context.drawImage(peaceImage, peaceX[2] - (peaceSize/2), peaceY[2], peaceSize, peaceHeight);
                }
            }

            function checkPos(mouseEvent){
                if(mouseEvent.pageX || mouseEvent.pageY == 0){
                    mouseX = mouseEvent.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                    mouseY = mouseEvent.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                }else if(mouseEvent.offsetX || mouseEvent.offsetY == 0){
                    mouseX = mouseEvent.offsetX;
                    mouseY = mouseEvent.offsetY;
                }
                for(i = 0; i < buttonX.length; i++){
                    if(mouseX > buttonX[i] && mouseX < buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i]){
                        if(mouseY > buttonY[i] && mouseY < buttonY[i] + buttonHeight[i]){
                            peaceVisible = true;
                            peaceX[0] = buttonX[i] - (peaceWidth/2) - 2;
                            peaceY[0] = buttonY[i] + 2;
                            peaceX[1] = buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i] + (peaceWidth/2); 
                            peaceY[1] = buttonY[i] + 2;
                        }
                    }else{
                        peaceVisible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function checkClick(mouseEvent){
                for(i = 0; i < buttonX.length; i++){
                    if(mouseX > buttonX[i] && mouseX < buttonX[i] + buttonWidth[i]){
                        if(mouseY > buttonY[i] && mouseY < buttonY[i] + buttonHeight[i]){
                            fadeId = setInterval("fadeOut()", 1000/frames);
                            clearInterval(timerId);
                            canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
                            canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            function fadeOut(){
                context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.2)";
                context.fillRect (0, 0, width, height);
                time += 0.1;
                if(time >= 2){
                    clearInterval(fadeId);
                    time = 0;
                    timerId = setInterval("update()", 1000/frames);
                    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", checkPos);
                    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", checkClick);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible. One way would be to store a "state" variable then have a switch statement in your `update` function to do things differently based on the state. It's all up to how you want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to store the states somewhere. You could have them in variables or in an object, for instance...

```
var ScreenState = {
    MENU : 0,
    GAMEPLAY : 1,
    SETTINGS : 2
}
```

Then, you simply need to conditionally update or draw your game, based on the current state.

e.g.

```
function update() {
    switch (currentScreenState) {
    case ScreenState.MENU:
        // Update the menu screen.
        break;
    case ScreenState.GAMEPLAY:
        // Update the gameplay screen.
        break;
    case ScreenState.SETTINGS:
        // Update the settings screen.
        break;
    }
}

function draw() {
    switch (currentScreenState) {
    case ScreenState.MENU:
        // Draw the menu screen.
        break;
    case ScreenState.GAMEPLAY:
        // Draw the gameplay screen.
        break;
    case ScreenState.SETTINGS:
        // Draw the settings screen.
        break;
    }
}
```

Normally, update() and draw() are called one after the other repeatedly in your game loop. And you then change your states depending on your updates or user input, etc. The game can then only display one state at a time based on your switch statement.

All that said, I would recommend that you use HTML for your screens involving menus/text and only deal with the canvas for your actual gameplay screens. This way, you only need to cope with your gameplay states and you can still do some fancy stuff with screen management and swapping screens in and out. I normally have each screen as a distinct object with child components that are either simply GameComponents (update only) or DrawableGameComponents (both updateable and drawable). Then, each screen can be kept discreet and code and state is then easier to manage and maintain.

Answer (score 3):

**Make each state an object.** If you are comfortable with JS inheritance, you can use prototypes for this; otherwise, you can just define each state with the same methods, as below:

```
menuState = {
  update: function() {
    //...
  }
}

settingsState = {
  update: function() {
    //...
  }
}

playState = {
  update: function() {
    this.clear();
    this.move();
    this.draw();
  },
  clear: function() {
    //...
  },
  move: function() {
    //...
  }
  draw: function() {
    //...
  }
}
```

This way, you can just have a variable that tracks which state you're in (e.g. `currentState = playState;`), and call `currentState.update()` when appropriate. This keeps each state's logic self-contained instead of scattering `switch` statements all over your code.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I do something similar with game screens and components/drawable components, whereby each has their own update or update/draw methods respectively. The swapping of screens or changing of individual state e.g. PLAYING/PAUSED, still needs to be managed, but it's far easier to manage discreet chunks of functionality and behavior like this. Nice :)